# Cypher - Search for a repeated connection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph model like so:

[image: Model]

As you can see, there are user nodes (blue) that are connected to resource nodes (various colors). I'm trying to find a query that will give me the users that are related to each other (like the ones in the example), but ignoring the resource nodes.

Something in the sorts of `(u:user)-([:HAS_RESOURCE]-(r:resource)-[])*1..5-(u2:user)`. I'm trying to ignore the intermediate resource nodes and find the actual affinity between the user nodes. So instead of getting a user who's related to another user on 2 levels (`user1->resource<-user2`), I want to be able to search for the relation to the user and specify levels without taking the resource nodes into account.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am not really sure I follow. What kind of result set are you seeking for your query given the sample diagram provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return, for each `user` node (`u`), a collection (`otherUsers`) of the distinct `user` nodes that are connected to `u` via 2 or more `HAS_RESOURCE` relationships:

```
MATCH (u:user)-[:HAS_RESOURCE*]-(u2:user)
RETURN u, COLLECT(DISTINCT u2) AS otherUsers;
```